# Given username and fork name, how to get the name of the source GitHub repo using Github API (v3)

Tags: github, github-api

I'm struggling with getting the name of the original repo, given name of the forked repository (same as the source repo name) and a particular username (who forked in the first place).

I tried using `https://api.github.com/users/:user/repos` API call, which doesn't contain this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the repository name and the username, yes? Let's look at what we can do.

To get all the information the API will return to you about a given repository, you can do:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/:username/:repository_name
```

This will give you data that looks like

```
{
  "id": 1296269,
  "owner": {
    "login": "octocat",
    "id": 1,
    "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  },
  "name": "Hello-World",
  "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
  "description": "This your first repo!",
  "private": false,
  "fork": false,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
  "archive_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
  "assignees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
  "blobs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
  "branches_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
  "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
  "collaborators_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
  "comments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
  "commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
  "compare_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
  "contents_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
  "contributors_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
  "deployments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
  "downloads_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
  "events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
  "forks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
  "git_commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
  "git_refs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
  "git_tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
  "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
  "hooks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks",
  "issue_comment_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
  "issue_events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
  "issues_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
  "keys_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
  "labels_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
  "languages_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
  "merges_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
  "milestones_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
  "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World",
  "notifications_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since, all, participating}",
  "pulls_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
  "releases_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
  "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
  "stargazers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
  "statuses_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
  "subscribers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
  "subscription_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
  "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
  "tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
  "teams_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
  "trees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "language": null,
  "forks_count": 9,
  "stargazers_count": 80,
  "watchers_count": 80,
  "size": 108,
  "default_branch": "master",
  "open_issues_count": 0,
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_wiki": true,
  "has_pages": false,
  "has_downloads": true,
  "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
  "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
  "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
  "permissions": {
    "admin": false,
    "push": false,
    "pull": true
  },
  "subscribers_count": 42,
  "organization": {
      ...
  },
  "parent": {
    "id": 1296269,
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "private": false,
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "archive_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "collaborators_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "comments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
    "commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
    "compare_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "contents_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
    "contributors_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
    "deployments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
    "downloads_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
    "events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
    "forks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
    "git_commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "hooks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks",
    "issue_comment_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
    "issue_events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
    "issues_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
    "keys_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
    "labels_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
    "languages_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
    "merges_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
    "milestones_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
    "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "notifications_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since, all, participating}",
    "pulls_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
    "releases_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "stargazers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
    "statuses_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
    "subscribers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
    "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "teams_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "trees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "language": null,
    "forks_count": 9,
    "stargazers_count": 80,
    "watchers_count": 80,
    "size": 108,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
    "permissions": {
      "admin": false,
      "push": false,
      "pull": true
    }
  },
  "source": {
    "id": 1296269,
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "private": false,
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "archive_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "collaborators_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "comments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
    "commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
    "compare_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "contents_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
    "contributors_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
    "deployments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
    "downloads_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
    "events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
    "forks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
    "git_commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "hooks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks",
    "issue_comment_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
    "issue_events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
    "issues_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
    "keys_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
    "labels_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
    "languages_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
    "merges_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
    "milestones_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
    "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "notifications_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since, all, participating}",
    "pulls_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
    "releases_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "stargazers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
    "statuses_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
    "subscribers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
    "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "teams_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "trees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "language": null,
    "forks_count": 9,
    "stargazers_count": 80,
    "watchers_count": 80,
    "size": 108,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
    "permissions": {
      "admin": false,
      "push": false,
      "pull": true
    }
  }
}
```

But what we really want to focus on here is this:

```
  "parent": {
    "id": 1296269,
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "private": false,
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "archive_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "collaborators_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "comments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
    "commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
    "compare_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "contents_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
    "contributors_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
    "deployments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
    "downloads_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
    "events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
    "forks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
    "git_commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "hooks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks",
    "issue_comment_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
    "issue_events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
    "issues_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
    "keys_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
    "labels_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
    "languages_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
    "merges_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
    "milestones_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
    "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "notifications_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since, all, participating}",
    "pulls_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
    "releases_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "stargazers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
    "statuses_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
    "subscribers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
    "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "teams_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "trees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "language": null,
    "forks_count": 9,
    "stargazers_count": 80,
    "watchers_count": 80,
    "size": 108,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
    "permissions": {
      "admin": false,
      "push": false,
      "pull": true
    }
  },
  "source": {
    "id": 1296269,
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
    "description": "This your first repo!",
    "private": false,
    "fork": true,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "archive_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/{archive_format}{/ref}",
    "assignees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/assignees{/user}",
    "blobs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs{/sha}",
    "branches_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/branches{/branch}",
    "clone_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "collaborators_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/collaborators{/collaborator}",
    "comments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/comments{/number}",
    "commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits{/sha}",
    "compare_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/compare/{base}...{head}",
    "contents_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contents/{+path}",
    "contributors_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/contributors",
    "deployments_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/deployments",
    "downloads_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/downloads",
    "events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/events",
    "forks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/forks",
    "git_commits_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/commits{/sha}",
    "git_refs_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/refs{/sha}",
    "git_tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/tags{/sha}",
    "git_url": "git:github.com/octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "hooks_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/hooks",
    "issue_comment_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/comments{/number}",
    "issue_events_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events{/number}",
    "issues_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues{/number}",
    "keys_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/keys{/key_id}",
    "labels_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/labels{/name}",
    "languages_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/languages",
    "merges_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/merges",
    "milestones_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/milestones{/number}",
    "mirror_url": "git:git.example.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "notifications_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/notifications{?since, all, participating}",
    "pulls_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls{/number}",
    "releases_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases{/id}",
    "ssh_url": "git@github.com:octocat/Hello-World.git",
    "stargazers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/stargazers",
    "statuses_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/{sha}",
    "subscribers_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscribers",
    "subscription_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/subscription",
    "svn_url": "https://svn.github.com/octocat/Hello-World",
    "tags_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/tags",
    "teams_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/teams",
    "trees_url": "http://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees{/sha}",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "language": null,
    "forks_count": 9,
    "stargazers_count": 80,
    "watchers_count": 80,
    "size": 108,
    "default_branch": "master",
    "open_issues_count": 0,
    "has_issues": true,
    "has_wiki": true,
    "has_pages": false,
    "has_downloads": true,
    "pushed_at": "2011-01-26T19:06:43Z",
    "created_at": "2011-01-26T19:01:12Z",
    "updated_at": "2011-01-26T19:14:43Z",
    "permissions": {
      "admin": false,
      "push": false,
      "pull": true
    }
  }
```

These two parts of the response define the immediate parent (in the case that someone forked a fork) and the source which is the root node of the fork graph.

So let's say you have this JSON body parsed from the `GET` request above, then you can access the source like so:

```
body['source']
```

That then has an `owner` object inside of it as well as the `name` of the repository so you can do:

```
body['source']['owner']['login']
```

To get the username of the person or organization who owns the source and then

```
body['source']['name']
```

To find out the source's repository name.

Comment: Thankyou @sigmavirus24! I did try this endpoint yesterday but completely missed out on the information. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the username and name of the forked repo, you can call:

```
GET /repos/:user/:name
```

to return a JSON payload that will include both a `parent` and `source` field. From [the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get):

> The `parent` and `source` objects are present when the repository is a fork. `parent` is the repository this repository was forked from, `source` is the ultimate source for the network.

Comment: Thank you @kfb. This is really helpful! :)